# How does the relational operator == work in C?

Tags: c, relational-operators

I thought the relational operator == returns 0 when the statement to be checked is false and 1 when it is true. However, this is not what I am getting as output in a segment of code. Can anyone please explain?

I have tried looking up the internet for this but everywhere I have found the same explanation that I know.

```
int main()
{
    int x=35;

    printf("\n%d %d %d",x==35,x=50,x>40);

    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be: 1 50 1
But the output showed is: 0 50 0

Comment: What you are expecting is unspecified behavior. The order in which printf performs the operations is not standard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior)

Comment: Do not vote to close this. It's not a dupe and it's not a simple typgraphical error.

Answer (score 6):

The behavior of code that has both `x == 35` and `x = 50` in the arguments to a function is not defined by the C standard, because it both modifies `x` and separately uses its value, and the rules of C does not say which happens first. C 2018 6.5 2 says:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.

In `x = 50`, the main value is 50, and the side effect is to change the value stored in `x` to 50.

In `x == 35`, the expression is a value computation that uses the value of `x`.

In general, evaluations of subexpressions are unsequenced, because C 2018 6.5 3 says:

> Except as specified later, side effects and value computations of subexpressions are unsequenced

C 2018 6.5.2.2 specifies what happens with function calls, and it does not specify the order in which arguments are evaluated. So 6.5 3, quoted above, applies. `x = 50` and `x == 35` are unsequenced. So there is both a side effect on `x` and a value computation of `x` that are unsequenced, so 6.5 2 applies, and the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem is this was given in a standard handbook of C and nowhere was it mentioned that this kind of code is unsequenced. Thanks again for helping.

Comment: @MayukhBanerjee: The book is wrong. This fact about C is very well known.

Comment: @MayukhBanerjee it is harder to fix books than SO Q/A

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```
printf("\n%d %d %d",x==35,x=50,x>40);
```

modifies `x` such that (in this case) when the test `x==35` is performed, `x` is equal to 50.

The order of evaluation of function parameters is undefined, so in other cases results may differ.  Such code should be avoided.  Consider:

```
printf( "\n%d", x == 35 ) ;
printf( "%d", x = 50 ) ;
printf( "%d", x > 40 ) ;
```

which is well defined and will produce the result you expected.

Note that the language defines zero and *non-zero* as representing false and true respectively rather than zero and one specifically.